# Neo4j 2.0 Cypher: Difference between Skip Limit vs. Range( ) vs. collect(n) with col[x..y]

Tags: neo4j

When processing large batches and using skip/limit or range, I've noticed (and so have many others) that performance seems to degrade quite a bit the higher the skip/range start number is.

I'm wondering if there is a performance improvement when using collect(n) as col with col[x..y]?

I've tried it..kind of.  I'm also not sure if they would return the same nodes in the same order.

Assuming that I have a total count of (n:LotsOfNodes) and I send the below cypher queries in batches of 500:

```
MATCH (n:LotsOfNodes) WHERE has(n.OtherNodeId)
WITH collect(n) as AllNodes
WITH AllNodes[30000..30500] as rangeNodes
FOREACH (a in rangeNodes | 
  MERGE (b:OtherNode {id:a.OtherNodeId})
  MERGE (a)-[r:RELATE_A_TO_B]->(b)
)
```

Will the above relate the same nodes as:

```
MATCH (a:LotsOfNodes)
,(b:OtherNode {id:a.OtherNodeId})
WITH a,b SKIP 30000 LIMIT 500
MERGE (a)-[r:RELATE_A_TO_B]->(b)
```

and:

```
MATCH (a:LotsOfNodes) WHERE has(a.OtherNodeId)
WITH collect(n) as AllNodes
FOREACH (i in range(30000,30500) |
 FOREACH (a in [AllNodes[i]] | 
   MERGE (b:OtherNode {id:a.OtherNodeId})
   MERGE (a)-[r:RELATE_A_TO_B]->(b)
 )
)
```

I've tried all three of these queries and I am either having some serious performance issues when using skip/range or it errors out when I take out the `WHERE` clause. Sometimes `(a)` doesn't have property `OtherNodeId` because it was set to `null` during import.

The point of the first query is to see if there are performance issues, and for the most part, it seems fine (but now I'm concerned I'm not actually grabbing all of the nodes).

Another weird thing is that sometimes, it runs fast per batch of 500 (<500ms) and other times it takes a whopping 42 SECONDS per batch.  The 42 second issue always comes up on the same (:Label) so it may be something weird with the properties in that node, but I can't figure out what... the properties I'm querying against are all Indexed and set as Unique.

---

Edit from Wes' comments:  Trying to see if passing in each list as params might help performance - where [listTarget] is batched but [listSource] is always sending in the full list:

```
FOREACH (x in [listTarget] | 
  FOREACH (n in [listSource] | 
    MERGE (s:SourceLabel {sourceId : x.sourceId} )
    -[r:RELATIONTYPE]->
    (t:TargetLabel {targetId : x.targetId}) 
    SET s = n, t = x, r.sourceId = s.sourceId , r.targetId = t.targetId 
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few points. Sorry it's not more thorough, but it was too big to fit in a comment, so here's a brief answer.

1. range() simply generates a collection (it doesn't hit the files at all), so it's generally a quick operation.
2. SKIP/LIMIT should not be used without ORDER BY and some unique key to order by (if you have nothing better, use the node id). ORDER is not guaranteed with SKIP/LIMIT, and it's especially unlikely if you're adding new records to the same label while running it.
3. I have a feeling the slowdowns in your MERGE are the cases where the OtherNode already exists. It's faster to CREATE than MATCH. I could be wrong about this, though--42 seconds seems awfully long. Can you check to messages.log during that time to see if something weird happened?

In 2.1 they're releasing a new Cypher feature: PERIODIC COMMIT, which should help with some of these problems.

Comment: Thanks Wes!  So, would skip/limit perform fine if I order by an indexed ID (even if I'm skipping 40000 nodes)?  The only problem I have with RANGE is in the merge statement, I'm trying to match nodes of two labels that share a property, but sometimes that property doesn't exist - and this causes the entire transaction to fail.  That's where the first query helps.  I've been refactoring my code but once I'm ready to start some more test runs, I'll take a look at the log and report back.  How does RANGE order the collection?

Comment: it won't use the index to help sort (yet). :( 40k isn't so bad, but if you're trying to go to millions I would be worried about performance.

Comment: 40k in batches of 500 starts to take a couple of seconds per batch after around 20k.  I'm working on outputting my results to console so I can post some more details.

Comment: I have a feeling you could probably do it faster if you were to reimport and create the rels as they go in, rather than using this property to lookup and create them after the import. (assuming that's what you're doing).

Comment: Maybe for your match you could check to see if they're not connected AND have an OtherNodeId, rather than doing the limit/skip.

Comment: Would something like the following work for importing and relating at the same time? Passing in as params ListTarget and ListSource - where ListTarget is batched but ListSource passes in all x number of items
                    FOREACH (x in [listTarget] |
                      FOREACH (n in [listSource] |
                      MERGE (s:SourceLabel {sourceId : x.sourceId} )-[r:RELATIONTYPE]->(t:TargetLabel)
                      SET s = n, t = x,  r.sourceId = s.sourceId , r.targetId = t.targetId
                    ))

Comment: Wow, that's hard to read... I'm adding it to my question above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48702/discussion-between-dcinzona-and-wes-freeman)